# python cherrypy: serve css file

Tags: python, css, cherrypy, webfaction

I'm using webfaction as a webhost. I'm trying to serve my cherrypy application a css file but something isn't working. I've got my python application in

```
home/webapps/spotipy
```

and my css file in

```
home/webapps/spotipy/css
```

At the top of my python code I've got

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.2
import cherrypy

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):

        return '''<html> 
                  <head>
                    <title>Spoti.py</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_css.css" type="text/css" />
                  </head>
                  <p> hi </p>

                  <body>
                  <p> hi joey </p>
        %s
        </body></html>''' %text
```

And this at the bottom

```
cherrypy.quickstart(Root(),config={

        '/css':
        { 'tools.staticdir.on':True,
          'tools.staticdir.dir':"home/webapps/spotipy/css"
        },
        '/my_css.css':
        { 'tools.staticfile.on':True,
          'tools.staticfile.filename':"home/webapps/spotipy/css/my_css.css"
        }
    })
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "something isn't working"? I guess you get 404 while serving css, am i right?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very specific. I get no error. Its just that none of my formatting contained in the my_css.css file is applied to the website.

Comment: Can you access css file directly?

Comment: as in use the absolute path to it?

Comment: I was thinking more about: http://your-host/css/your-css-file.css

Answer (score 2):

This is a complete working example below in addition to zero323 answer. Change the shebang and run it in your /home/webapps/spotipy directory.
If it does not work, there may be browser cache issue so refresh your page with Ctrl+F5.
You can check if the css file is loaded correctly by pressing Ctrl+U to see the page source and click to see the pointing css links. If everything seems normal and still your css file does not apply on your page, it may be a css issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import cherrypy

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        text="dummy text"
        return '''<html> 
                  <head>
                    <title>Spoti.py</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/my_css.css" type="text/css" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/joey_css.css" type="text/css" />
                  </head>
                  <p> hi </p>

                  <body>
                  <p> hi joey </p>
        %s
        </body></html>''' %text

conf={"/css": {"tools.staticdir.on": True,
               "tools.staticdir.dir": os.path.abspath("./css"),},
       '/joey_css.css':
                    { 'tools.staticfile.on':True,
                      'tools.staticfile.filename': os.path.abspath("./css/my_css.css"),
                    }
               }

cherrypy.quickstart(Root(),config=conf)
```

Comment: Many thanks for a complete solution. It works well still in 2021 !

Answer (score 1):

Try using absolute paths instead of relative. I suppose you are messing things up by trying to access home/webapps/spotipy/css. Try this in config:

```
cherrypy.quickstart(Root(),config={

        '/css':
        { 'tools.staticdir.on':True,
          'tools.staticdir.dir': "/home/webapps/spotipy/css"
        },

        '/joey_css.css':
        { 'tools.staticfile.on':True,
          'tools.staticfile.filename': "/home/webapps/spotipy/css/my_css.css"
        }
    })
```

and this in html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/my_css.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: sorry, not working still. I even fixed the mistake. it says joey_css when it should be my_css

Comment: sorry, nothing yet :(